# rotating an icon with angular ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a collapsable dropdown vertical menu and I've got most of all the functionalities working except one that is eluding me. And that is, rotating the icon so that it shows up when it's open and pointing down when it's closed.

I have a [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/pRNLwo) that you can use. I've updated the code below to show the changes that are now closest to the solution.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="cnt">
    <div class="menu-item" ng-click="toggle(1); open1=!open1">
        <md-list layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
            <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item</span>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-down rotate180': open1, 'fa fa-chevron-down': !open1}"></i>
        </md-list>
        <div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
            <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen===1" ng-repeat="item in data"  >
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item" ng-click="toggle(2); open2=!open2">
        <md-list layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
            <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item 2</span>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-down rotate180': open2, 'fa fa-chevron-down': !open2}"></i>
        </md-list>
        <div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
            <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen===2" ng-repeat="item in data2">
                <md-button>
                    <div layout="row" flex="">
                        <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                            <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is what's inside my controller. The toggle function is workout and I figured, it would probably be a good idea to attach the icon rotation to this function so that they work together. But I am having a hard time figuring it out. The closest I got to it was with this function below. But it changes all the icons in the same click

```
$scope.open1 = false; //initial value
$scope.open2 = false; //initial value

$scope.toggle = function(itemPos) {
    if ($scope.menuIsOpen === itemPos) {
        $scope.menuIsOpen = 0;
    }
    else {
        $scope.menuIsOpen = itemPos;
    }
}
```

Either an AngularJS or JavaScript solution will be fine. I'll prefer AngularJS. No Bootstrap suggestions please. This is an Angular Material application. It doesn't use Bootstrap. Thanks again!

Comment: Is it adding the class or giving any console error??

Comment: no errors. I technically didn't violate any Javascript or Angular rule, it's just not built logically

Comment: I think it's not finding the element.. So why don't you try to get it directly from the menu-item class . and try finding in its children.. Instead of using closest and find...

Comment: I think I tried that and I could be wrong, but the actual condition is in the md-menu-item ng-if="....". The menu-item div has the click listener to fire the function but not the condition. If you check my codepen, it has angular code instead javascript but it is doing all of the icons instead of the one that is being clicked on. I think this could work if I could get help with isolating the event.

Comment: The problem is you have 2 menu items to handle, but you just have one common `class` and `menuIsOpen` properties. Ideally each menu object should have these properties and your code will work fine. I've  logged in via mobile and did some quick tweak in your code and is working fine.

Comment: @Developer menuIsOpen is isolated by the parameters in the function. That's why not all menus open in one click. I can't replicate the same logic in the icon rotation. I thought by putting the rotation scope call inside the toggle conditional if-statement it would work but it doesn't. Where can I see these tweaks you made? I can't find them in my codepen or here. Thanks for looking into this from your phone

Comment: My bad, I had no clue how to save the changes I made and while reverting some change, I clicked the mobile back button which ended up closing that browser. Let me explain what I did (gotta refactor it properly, just a logic) - change your first menu class="class1" and second item to class="class2". Now in the toggle class `var className="class"+itemPos;` and use this instead of `$scope.class` like `$scope[className]`

Comment: @Developer an array? What is in the className array?

Comment: Thats not an array, in javascript, `obj.name` is same as `obj[name]`. As the `className` value is dynamic, I used that syntax

Comment: Ah ok, I see. hmm. I wish I could tell you I know exactly what to do with your suggestions but I'm at a loss lol. My javascript is still a little rough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you need to animate the opening and closure of the menu icon you could also apply 2 different CSS classes with different CSS transform properties.

And use ng-class accordingly using 2 expressions:

**HTML**

```
ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-down rotate180': open1, 'fa fa-chevron-down rotate-back': !open1}"
```

**CSS CLASSES**

```
.rotate180 {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition: all linear 200ms;
    transition: all linear 200ms;
}

.rotate-back {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: all linear 200ms;
    transition: all linear 200ms;
}
```

**CODEPEN**

http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/zNEPoW

Comment: It is still rotating all icons at once. Notice in your codepen, when you open the menu on top, the icon on the bottom menu also rotates.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. You and jbrown were both really close. I gave you the answer because of completion. I do think the rotate-back class was needed.

Comment: Thank you, happy to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a $scope variable named opened and set it 0.

Toggle its value in your ng-click based on which menu is clicked like this ... opened=1;

And use it with your ng-class:

```
<i ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-up': opened===1, 'fa fa-chevron-down': opened!==1}"></i>
```

You'd do this for each menu using a different number to identify it, 1,2,3...

Comment: That is kind of what I have already only I had it integrated inside my toggle class. And it affects all icons, not just the one being clicked. I updated the codepen with your code.

Comment: You'd need a separate 'open' var for each menu.

Comment: This is the closest answer so far man. Good stuff, but, there is a problem. because the open is not attached to the actual condition of being open or closed, it toggles like this open = open++ which means, if you open the first one, it toggles up. Good! but then you open the bottom one and obviously that closes the top one but the icon remains up. It makes the icon positions inconsistent :(

Comment: Okay, I'd go back to using a single var that is a number that corresponds with the menu.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I wish I could check two answers as answers lol Thanks a lot for your help.